# How to get value of another array?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I want to get array like below

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
        [product_id] => 6
        [price] => 50.0000
        [quantity] => 5
        [option] => Array (
                [option_display] => Array (
                        [Color] => black
                        [RAM] => 2GB
                    )

                [option_details] => Array (
                        [7] => 15
                        [8] => 16
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 6
        [price] => 50.0000
        [quantity] => 4
        [option] => Array
            (
                [option_display] => Array
                    (
                        [Cover Type] => flip
                        [Description] => leather type
                    )

                [option_details] => Array
                    (
                        [7] => flip
                        [8] => leather type
                    )

            )

    ) )
```

In the above code `option_display` are the values to display and in `option_details` id to store in db.(Note: `flip` and `leather type` are field and text area
15 and 16 are select box and radio box so it has id)

and my html file is

```
case 'drop_down':
            echo $value->getTitle();
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="option_display['.$value->getTitle().']" id="option_display_'.$value->getTitle().'" />';
            echo '<div><p class="'.(($value->getIsRequire() == 1) ? 'required' : '').'">'.(($value->getIsRequire() == 1) ? '*Required Field' : '').'</p><select name="option_value['.$value->getOptionId().']">';
            foreach ($option as $values) {
                echo '<option value="'.$values['option_type_id'].'" id="option_value_'.$value->getOptionId().'">'.$values['title'].' + '.Mage::helper('core')->currency($values['price'], true, false).'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select></div>';
            break;
```

I got array values

```
$newdata        = array (
            'product_id' => $product_id,
            'price'      => $price,
            'quantity'   => $quantity,
            'option'     => array(
                'option_display' => $option_display,
                'option_details' => $option_value
                )
        );
```

In `option_details` get key as id of color and RAM and values id. In `option display` i got key as color and RAM but i dont know how to get values (i.e., black and 2gb).i want to get vales not id what i have to do for this.

Answer (score 1):

> Change the foreach loop to below method:-

```
   foreach ($option as $values => $value) {
                echo '<option value="'.$value['option_type_id'].'" id="option_value_'.$value->getOptionId().'">'.$value['title'].' + '.Mage::helper('core')->currency($values['price'], true, false).'</option>';
            }
```

Comment: I got same output. I just want to get values for option_display.... but my output is coming like this   [6] => Array ( [product_id] => 14  [price] => 10010.0000 [quantity] => 3
            [option] => Array ( [option_display] => Array  ( [Color] =>  [RAM] =>  )  [option_details] => Array (  [5] => 13  [6] => 16 )  ) )

Comment: color and RAM is empty

Comment: In beetween of foreach loop you use below method to get value echo $value[option_display][Color];

Comment: still i did'nt get anything

Comment: How to get the array value? using db check query.